# Gerar HASH do conteúdo XML em SQL

Tags: sql, xml, hash

Existe uma forma de gerar o `hash` de um `XML` além da função `master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary`?

Atualmente essa é minha implementação, porém, não sei se é o único jeito de se fazer.

```
--Preparação do ambiente
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Funcionarios]([FuncionarioId] [int] NOT NULL, [Nome] [varchar](50) NULL)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionarios] (FuncionarioId, Nome) values(1,'jose')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionarios] (FuncionarioId, Nome) values(2,'maria')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionarios] (FuncionarioId, Nome) values(3,'joão')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Funcionarios] (FuncionarioId, Nome) values(4,'pedro')

DECLARE @XML XML
DECLARE @HASH CHAR(32)

--Esse é um select de exemplo
SELECT @XML = (select * FROM Funcionarios FOR XML PATH('FUNC'))

--Gero o hash com essa função
SET @HASH = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(CAST((SELECT @XML).value('.','VARCHAR(max)') AS VARBINARY(MAX))), 2);

--Crio um outro xml incluindo o hash na tag epílogo
WITH 
    XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd,
                  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
    SELECT @XML = (SELECT 
                        (SELECT @XML
                                , (SELECT @HASH 'xml:hash'
                                   FOR XML PATH ('xml:epilogo'), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
                         FOR XML PATH('xml:teste'),ELEMENTS,TYPE)
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)

--Resultado final
SELECT @XML 'XML'
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso o que você pode fazer é criar um [CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx) e fazer o hash via CLR que no caso seria em C#.

[Veja esse exemplo](https://www.sandersdenardi.com/hashing-with-sql-server-clr/)

Comment: Em `CLR` `c#` eu já fiz. Como solução alternativa, construí em `SQL` para não ter que registrar o `assembly` no servidor do cliente. Como minha aplicação cresceu, formalizei um `CLR`. A pergunta ainda ficará para encontrar outra solução em `SQL`.